# Is there a way to mask the whole database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, encryption

I am new to SQL server and now I have a database with thousands of tables stored. I want to replicate this database and pass this replica to other vendors, but for security concern, I would like to mask all the fields in the tables. The vendors don't really care about what has stored in the table but they do care about the structures or distributions about the tables.

The idea is to copy the current database and do masking then. But I don't know if SQL server has provided this technique to simplify the process. Appreciate it for any comments or suggestions!

Comment: so for short you don't need the data just the table structure?

Comment: we need the tables, but they can be like fake tables. ER diagram would be not enough for now.

Comment: i'm asking if you need the data or not, so you can truncate the table instead of doing the masking. i believe masking is available in sql server 2016.

Comment: with Miscrosft SSMS, you can right click the database and select task then you can find Copy Database option.

Comment: truncate the tables might not work for me. One thing I want to show to the vendors is about how many records each table contains...

Comment: And the sql server version is 2012.

Comment: if you're asking for automated masking i think their is none for 2012. i suggest you update your data manually for masking.

Comment: Well, there _used_ to be an option in SSMS in earlier v18; right click DB | Tasks | Mask Database.  But I can't find it anymore using v18.1.

Answer (score 0):

Just deny view definition permission to the user who will access the database using the below query :-

```
USE master  
GO  
DENY VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO User1
```

Once you deny this permission to User1, all objects such as table,SP,view etc will be hidden in the database and at the sametime user1 will be able to do whatever he wants if he knows the object.

This will mask the all objects from the user.

Comment: If they're replicating the database and then passing it on to the vendor, this won't work as the vendor will have full access on the target system and can just lift this restriction.